# How can I make the bootstrap columns matchheights?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

[image]

How can I make the bootstrap columns matchheihts without puting rows in every 3 columns, these columns are from the database that I php foreach so I cannot put row.

I used matchHeight but not working, is there any other alternative way?

```
$(function() {
    $('.item').matchHeight(options);
    byRow: byRow
});


<script src="<?=base_url();?>assets/matcheight/jquery.matchHeight.js"
   type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `flexbox` to solve it. Apply this to your container:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Try this out and let me know if this works for you. Thanks!

Comment: wow, it works! :))  i been trying to solve this for 2 days. thank you sir!

Comment: i cant believe that the answer is just 2 lines of css. hahaha. thank you again!  :)

Comment: sir,? there is another problem, some of the colums are not matching the width. :(

Comment: the question was to adjust the height right? Can't do much without the code. Please post a new question with the full code for more improvements to your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/x-javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Select and loop the container element of the elements you want to equalise
    $('.container').each(function(){  

      // Cache the highest
      var highestBox = 0;

      // Select and loop the elements you want to equalise
      $('.col-md-4', this).each(function(){

        // If this box is higher than the cached highest then store it
        if($(this).height() > highestBox) {
          highestBox = $(this).height(); 
        }

      });  

      // Set the height of all those children to whichever was highest 
      $('.col-md-4',this).height(highestBox);

    }); 

});
</script>
```